# Bind Dictionary to Chart

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I'm new to Silverlight and I am trying to display the contents of a Dictionary in a Graph:

In codebehind:

```
ChartData = new Dictionary<DateTime, double> {{DateTime.Now, 10}, 
      {DateTime.Now, 20}, {DateTime.Now, 15}};
```

And in the silverlight XAML:

```
<toolkit:Chart HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="113,168,0,0" Name="chart1" 
   Title="Chart Title" VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <toolkit:LineSeries ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ChartData}"  
          DependentValuePath="Key" IndependentValuePath="Value">
    </toolkit:LineSeries>
</toolkit:Chart>
```

But this gives "No suitable axis is availible for plotting the dependent value". Suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this data set:-

```
ChartData = new Dictionary<DateTime, double>() { 
  { DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1), 10 }, 
  { DateTime.Now, 20 },
  { DateTime.Now.AddDays(1), 15 }
};
```

(I'm surprise your line of code even worked, since it would attempt to add multiple keys with the same value into the dictionary).

Then change your Xaml:-

```
<toolkit:LineSeries ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ChartData}"    
      DependentValuePath="Value" IndependentValuePath="Key">
```

Its would be highly unusual to use a date as a DependentValue, in fact I can't think of a scenario where a DependentValue would anything other than numeric.

Comment: One small addition: use `DependentValueBinding="{Binding Path=Value}" IndependentValueBinding="{Binding Path=Key}"` for the key/value bindings. Otherwise they won´t work :)

Comment: @Deruijter: Is that what the `xxxxxValuePath` properties end up doing?  That is to set the Binding on the `xxxxxValueBinding` properties.

Comment: Anthony, now that you mention it, I failed to notice you used Path instead of Binding! Your method actually works perfectly. I was already using `xxxxValueBinding` so when reading your answer I subconsciously assumed you were doing the same. To be honest I'm not sure `xxxxValuePath` is setting `xxxxValueBinding` behind the screens (I'm no xaml expert yet).. But I think that could very well be the case.